# SED - insert a blank line after every input line that consists of capital letters and spaces

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a text file and I need a command using `sed` to insert a blank line after every line that that consists of capital letters and spaces only.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^[[:blank:][:upper:]][[:blank:][:upper:]]*$/G' file
```

This appends the hold space (by default it contains a newline) to lines containing at least one or more whitespace or uppercase characters.

Comment: It also works with BSD and POSIX. This is the best `sed` solution. It does double a visibly blank line (ie, `^[[:space:]]$`) but this is the best `sed` solution.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
$ cat file
LINE LINE LINE
Line Line Line
Line 1
LINE 2
END!
====
```

You can use `s///` to add a `\n` to the line:

With POSIX sed, use a literal new line in the sed script:

```
$ sed 's/^\([[:upper:][:blank:]]*\)$/\1\
/' file
LINE LINE LINE

Line Line Line
Line 1
LINE 2
END!
====
```

With GNU sed, you can use the representation of `\n`:

```
$ sed 's/^\([[:upper:][:blank:]]*\)$/\1\n/' file
```

---

You can also use `a\` to append in sed. I have tried to get sed `append` to work but cannot reliably with POSIX, BSD and GNU sed since POSIX and BSD do not support `\n`

With GNU sed (note space after `a\`):

```
 $ sed '/^[[:upper:][:blank:]]*$/a\ ' file
```

BSD:

```
$ sed '/^[[:upper:][:blank:]]*$/a\ 
\
' file
```

Those are not exactly equivalent since the GNU version has a space on the blank line.

The version of POSIX sed I have did not work with either of those...

---

Given the platform and version differences of `sed`, you might consider `awk` to do this since simple awk's are easier to make universal.

This works on every `awk` I have:

```
$ awk '1; /^[[:upper:][:blank:]]*$/{print ""}' file
```

With `awk` you can also make it so that blank lines are not doubled by making sure there is at least non blank like so:

```
 $ awk '1; /^[[:upper:][:blank:]]+$/ && NF>1 {print ""}' file
```

Comment: You could use an append instead of a substitute.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I thought of doing that, but `a` is not quite as easily expressed cross platform GNU and POSIX as a substitution is. POSIX does not support `\n` and the literal line feed trick does not work. (At least in my little testing) Do you know how to append a linefeed with POSIX sed?

Comment: (Note that `-E` is not POSIX.)  I'd expect to use ```/^[[:upper:][:blank:]]*$/a\``` with an actual newline after the backslash (as in your POSIX example), and single quotes around the whole lot.  Or in a file over two lines (used with `sed -f sed.script`).  That'll work with any classic `sed`; AFAIK, it also works with GNU `sed`, but it is a law unto itself and has various notations that are not POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just insert lines with `a`:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]A-Z]*$/a\'
```

The `a` command inserts the string after it after every matching line (end the string with a backslash). So the above command just inserts an empty line after all lines that contains solely of capital letters and spaces. That's exactly what you want.